# Ubuntu 16.04 Bluetooth 'Send files' is not working

Tags: bluetooth

In my laptop i'm able to connect to another device (mobile) via Bluetooth.

But when i click on 'Send files' and select a file to send, nothing happens.

Some more details:

```
$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep Blue
[   15.990119] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   15.990152] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.990158] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.990161] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.990171] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.399440] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000300.bin
[   16.399444] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x300 build 0x3e8, firmware rome 0x300 build 0x111
[   16.496583] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000300.bin
[   32.664262] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   32.664265] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   32.664271] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   46.857158] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   46.857172] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   46.857181] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30)
  Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:4035]
  Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
  Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13d3:a745 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e360 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Sending files from other device (mobile) to laptop is also failing.
(just says file is not sent)

Comment: Upgrading to 17.10 fixed this problem. But 17.10 has made my system highly unstable, don't upgrade.

Comment: Reinstalled `16.04`, bluetooth send files is working. UI seems to buggy though.